# JSONObject only copy last value of HashMap

Tags: java, android, json

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("ID", 1);
    map.put("ID", 2);
    map.put("ID", 3);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(map);
    Log.e("JSON", jsonObject.toString());
```

OutPut:E/JSON: {"ID":3} Its Funny!!!!

I expect to obtain something like

```
{"ID":1},{"ID":2},{"ID":3}
```

Comment: what do you expect or trying to achive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. `Map#put` overrides the value if a key already exits. In your case:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("ID", 1);
map.put("ID", 2);
map.put("ID", 3);
```

you are reusing the key `"ID"`. Your map contains only one pair `key/value` `ID/3`. From the documentation ([HashMap#put](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V)))

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If
>   the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is
>   replaced.

On the other hand, the same json object can't contain the same key multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Json and Maps are key-based.

Your object key must be **unique**, otherwise it will be replaced.

You should use different keys:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("ID_1", 1);
map.put("ID_2", 2);
map.put("ID_3", 3);
```

or use array of maps.